# How to open css files in a readable format

Tags: css

I  want to open the CSS files in Atom editor but it is formatted in a difficult way thread.
any ideas to open CSS files in a nice CSS format.[CSS Files to open and read](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESGQv.png)

Comment: You are looking at *minified css*. You can just google search for *read minified css* and paste your code in any free online converter.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow _ The image you've linked to shows a `bootstrap.min.css` file _ `.min` means that all of the whitespace has been removed to 'miniaturise' the file for fast-reading by a machine _ If you open the corresponding `bootstrap.css` file it's exactly the same code but it still has all of the whitespace and is formatted in a much more human-readable style

Comment: Thanks guys for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To convert any **minified(unreadable)** file into **readable** form is called **beautify**.
The **extension, plugin, software or tool** which convert minified file into readable file is called **Beautifier / Formatter**.

*There are several methods to use it.* 
**Code Editor Extensions/Plugins**

- [cssbeautify (ATOM)](https://atom.io/packages/atom-beautify)
- [HTML-CSS-JS Prettify (Sublime Text)](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/HTML-CSS-JS%20Prettify)
- [brackets-beautify (Adobe Brackets)](https://www.npmjs.com/package/brackets-beautify)
- [Beautify (VS Code)](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=HookyQR.beautify)

**Bundlers and Task Runner Tools**

- [Prettier Webpack Plugin (Webpack)](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prettier-webpack-plugin)
- [gulp-cssbeautify (Gulp)](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-cssbeautify)

**Online Tools**

- [atom-beautify (https://atom.io/packages/atom-beautify)](https://www.cleancss.com/css-beautify/)
- [freeformatter (https://www.freeformatter.com/css-beautifier.html)](https://www.freeformatter.com/css-beautifier.html)
- [Minify Code (http://minifycode.com/css-beautifier/)](http://minifycode.com/css-beautifier/)

You can also use it with Developer tools in your favorite browser.